# mysql search part of string

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I've got the a field in a table in my database which contains the following HTML code:

```
<table class="table_productinfo" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td class="attribute_head"><strong>Ausführung:</strong></td><td><strong>500mm</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Farbe:</td><td>weiß glänzend</td></tr><tr><td class="attribute_head">Material:</td><td>Keramik</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Hersteller:</td><td>antoniolupi</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Serie:</td><td>ALBUM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Design:</td><td>Prospero Rasulo</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Bemerkung:</td><td>Auch zur Wandmontage geeignet</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Höhe in mm:</td><td>150</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Tiefe in mm:</td><td>500</td></tr><tr><td class="attribute_head">Breite in mm:</td><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><td class="attribute_head">Artikelnummer:</td><td>NLALB</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I'd like to submit a search string via php:

```
antoniolupi album prospero
```

What do I have to do to find this specific row with this content?

I tried stuff like splitting the keyword `explode(' ',$keyword)` and to find partial occurances, but I can't get the sql query I need to get.

Comment: Where does mysql play a role?

Comment: forget about "my", it was a sql thing :)

Answer (score 0):

In there where clause use the like search term on the column you are searching. Where column_name like '%search_term" after that you can just join all the search terms depending if you just need one to match or all of them to match.

Comment: oh my gosh.. the solution was so darn simple..
thanks for the reply! I had a mental block.. all I needed to do was:
where description LIKE '%antoniolupi%album%prospero%'

Thanks!!